# How to group an array of variables based on flags assigned to them with minimal code in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array that has four elements
example :

```
int[] a = new int[5];
```

the value would be like : `a[0] = 10,a[1]=5,a[2]=15,a[3]=10,a[4]=0;`

I have  flag ,

```
public bool[] flag = new bool[4]{false,false,false,false};
```

based on which I need to assign this above values to another variable named `b[5]`.

If the flag is `false`,it will `add` to the existing values of b  ,

else it will reset the values of `a` to `b`.

I have tried the following code which seems to be too lengthy

```
count[0]=20,count[1]=20;count[2]=20;count[3]=20;
flag[0]=true,flag[1]=true,flag[2]=true,flag[3]=false;

void display(int[] count,int[]flag)
{         
    if (flag[0] == true)
    {
        resetcount[0] = count[0];
    }
    if(flag[1]==true)
    {
        resetcount[1] = count[1];
    }
    if (flag[2] == true)
    {
        resetcount[2] = count[2];
    }
    if(flag[3]==true)
    {
        resetcount[3] = count[3];
    }
    if (flag[0] == false)
    {
        resetcount[0] += count[0];
    }
    if (flag[1] == false)
    {
        resetcount[1] += count[1];
    }
    if (flag[2] == false)
    {
        resetcount[2] += count[2];
    }
    if (flag[3] == false)
    {
        resetcount[3] += count[3];
    }
}
```

here `resetcount[0]=10,resetcount[1]=10,resetcount[2]=10,resetcount[3]=10;`

if all flag is false the count value will be added and if it is true the count value will be set to reset count
so as above it will be 0,1,2

```
count[0]=20,count[1]=20;count[2]=20;count[3]=20;
flag[0]=true,flag[1]=true,flag[2]=true,flag[3]=false;
resetcount[0]=10,resetcount[1]=10,resetcount[2]=10,resetcount[3]=10;
```

so now resetcount would be :

```
resetcount[0]=20,resetcount[1]=20,resetcount[2]=20,resetcount[3]=30;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like a loop?

```
count[0]=20,count[1]=20;count[2]=20;count[3]=20;
flag[0]=true,flag[1]=true,flag[2]=true,flag[3]=false;

void display(int[] count,int[]flag)
{         
  for (int i = 0 ; i<=3 ; i++)
  {
    if (flag[i])
    {
      resetcount[i] = count[i];
    }
    else
    {
      resetcount[i] += count[i];
    }
```

}

Comment: well this is what I wanted @JNF

Comment: here you mentioned in if condition directly if(flag[i]) will it directly accept as true??@JNF

Comment: @TechBrkTru any positive value is true

Comment: @TechBrkTru - By writing `if(something == true)` your if statement is evaluating whether the result of comparing two booleans is true (or false), but you already start with a boolean, so you can just use that

Comment: @Sayse :okay so it the start would be false then to it would work right??

Comment: `false == true = false` so yes, that would enter the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void Display(int[] resetCount, int[] count, bool[] flags)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < resetCount.Count(); i++)
        {
            resetCount[i] = this.Calculate(resetCount[i], count[i], flags[i]);
        }
    }

    public int Calculate(int resetCount, int count, bool flag)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            resetCount = count;
        }
        else
        {
            resetCount += count;
        }

        return resetCount;
    }
```